# Can't see installation window in Babylon 9 for Windows 7 - Problem with Java installation

Tags: windows-7, java, babylon

I have the following problem with my Windows 7 64bit OS. The *Install dictionary* window for Babylon 9 is grey. I cannot see the progress indicator bar or anything in it.

The same issue applies for Java runtime (latest version) or the installation window of VMWare Virtualization software. I had a clean install of Windows 7 a while ago and cannot find the real cause of the issue.

As a matter of fact, Java contol panel doesn't load, double clicking on Java icon in control panel just makes it flicker. It just dissapears, minimizing to taskbar won't restore again. I tried different versions, `jre6u24`, `jre6u14`, disabled antialising of my ATI Graphics Card and restored defaults, used Java flags, but still the same.

I really don't know how to fix it. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I made your title more precise -- maybe you could add a screenshot to show us what you mean. I guess it seems to be a more general problem of your Java installation.

Comment: Yes,it is my java installation problem.As a matter of fact,Java contol panel doesn't load,double clicking on java icon in control panel just makes it flicker,it just dissapears, minimizing to taskbar,won't restore again.I tried different versions, jre6u24,jre6u14,disabled antialising of my ATI Graphics Card and restored defaults,used java flags,but still the same.I really don't know how to fix it,here's the screenshot [link]http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/imagelv.png

Comment: In the future, please use the [edit] link to supply additional information (I updated your post now). Seems like a Java problem after all, maybe somebody comes up with a few ideas.